# SSRS Calculate percentages of row group from total

Tags: reporting-services, percentage, ssrs-2008-r2

Using SSRS 2010, I have a table which looks like:

```
       Description     Place-ref
       -----------     ---------
Group: House           3 (Count of place-ref)
Group: Flat            1 (Count of place-ref)
Total                  4 (Count of Place-ref)
```

It seems like such a simple thing but I am struggling to get the "count of place-ref" to show as a %age, eg. 75% and 25% respectively.  Changing the format just changes the look of the number to 300% and 100%.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have solved this.

=(100/(reportitems!Textbox12.value))*count(Fields!place-ref.value) where textbox12 is the total of the group (i.e. 4)